# Do I have to be admin to make requests to wp-admin/admin-post.php?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have developed a custom plugin and it all works fine when I'm logged in as admin.

My plugin collects details from a custom form the plugin creates. When the form is submitted it sends a POST request to `admin-post.php`. This works fine when logged in.

When I log out, and use the site as a normal user, the form submission just loads a blank page.

Here's my code:

```
add_action('admin_post_loan_app_form', function() {

    if(!isset($_POST['app_number']) || empty($_POST['app_number']))
    {
         redirectToFormWithError(ERROR_EMPTY_APP_NUMBER);
    }

    $_SESSION['lnloans']['app_number'] = $_POST['app_number'];
    $_SESSION['lnloans']['page'] = LOAN_DETAILS_FORM;

    redirectToForm();
});
```

How can I allow anyone to send the post request and not just admins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using `admin_post_nopriv_*` as [your post action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_post_(action))? Because [that is what you need to do to](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/admin-post.php) post as an unauthenticated user. I.e:

```
add_action('admin_post_nopriv_loan_app_form', function() { […]
```

As a secondary solution, consider using [XML-RPC WordPress API](https://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Extending) to post data if possible.